# javascript onclick in html confusion

Tags: java, javascript, html, onclick

I was going through some `java` code(which uses `playframework`) that provides some shopping cart functionality.The `html` page contains some `javascript`  (it uses `jquery`) which is something I have very little knowledge of.Looking through the html,I found a table like this

```
<table>
...
<td> 
<a href="" onclick="return addItem(${item.id});">buy</a>
</td>
...
</table>
```

(The template uses ${} to get dynamic values thru **playframework** template language)
In the entire code ,the only `addItem(itemId)` method I could find was in the `ShoppingCart` class which has this signature

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
...
}
```

When I searched for onclick ,I found this page
[onclick doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp),which gives the syntax of onclick as

```
onclick="SomeJavaScriptCode"
```

Going thru all the javascript code(it uses jquery and ejohn-templating)I couldn't find any method like 'addItem'

So,how does the `onclick` work?How would it know which method to invoke?Will it look in the entire code (javascript and java)to find a matching method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is it would only look for javascript methods and not java methods. Second is you can use debugging in firebug to reach to the method called.

Comment: thanks for the firebug suggestion..I found that function .It was embedded in the template and not as a separate js file,and all the time I was looking in the javascripts folder.

Answer (score 3):

somewhere you have an `addItem` method in your javascript code.  The code in the html is executing that method, not the `addItem` method you found in the java code.

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively simple.
It looks like your Java code is executed on the server side, and the JavaScript (including jQuery) is executed on the client side. So the ${item.id} is executed on the server, and onClick executes whatever javascript code you provide for it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know playframework, but the `addItem` should be javascript, and `public void addItem(Item item)` is java code. Both are not related

This `addItem` javascript function is somewhere. If you are unable to find it in your code base, you can use the console of your browser (or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox) to see this javascript function. Go to the *Script* tab and search for addItem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't access server side functions unless is via AJAX or something like it. Even then, it doesn't have direct access to the funcions, but to a page that access that.

Look more carefully for that function in your Javascript using firebug, or the google chrome console. It should be there.